# Как добавить элемент в последнее измерение тензора не создавая копии?

Tags: python, pytorch

Как добавить элемент в последнее измерение тензора. Подробнее в примере ниже:

```
a = torch.tensor([[[1, 1, 2, 3],
             [3, 2, 1, 3],
             [3, 2, 3, 2]],
            [[3, 2, 1, 2],
             [2, 3, 2, 2],
             [1, 2, 2, 3]]])
# Получить нужно тензор
b = torch.tensor([[[1, 1, 2, 3, 1],
             [3, 2, 1, 3, 1],
             [3, 2, 3, 2, 1]],
            [[3, 2, 1, 2, 1],
             [2, 3, 2, 2, 1],
             [1, 2, 2, 3, 1]]])
```

Метод cat решает проблему, но он возвращает копию. А мне нужно получить изменённый тензор.

Comment: Это тензор, а не кортеж